# Preserving Mathematica expressions in a textual form

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the proper way to convert Mathematica expressions *losslessly* to a string (a string kept in memory, not exported to a file)?

I am looking for a textual representation that

1. will preserve all information, including keeping special (and possibly atomic) objects, such as `SparseArray`, `Graph`, `Dispatch`, `CompiledFunction`, etc. intact.  E.g. cycling a `SparseArray` through this representation should keep it sparse (and not convert it to a normal list).
2. is relatively fast to cycle through (convert back and forth).

Is `ToString[expr, FullForm]` sufficient for this?  What about `ToString[expr, InputForm]`?

Note 1: This came up while trying to work around some bugs in `Graph` where the internal representation gets corrupted occasionally.  But I'm interested in an answer to the general question above.

Note 2: `Save` will surely do this, but it writes to files (probably possible to solve this using streams), and it only write definitions associated with symbols.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Do you just want to "save" an expression to restore later, or are you going to process the string?

Comment: Just save and restore.  In this particular case to work around bugs like https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/RRsfrHCjwRM/discussion .  Leonid's solution is probably the best.

Comment: That bug looks bad.  Does saving to another symbol work?  `jjHold = jj; IsomorphicGraphQ[jj, ...`

Comment: No.  It appears to be caused by corrupted (?) internal representation.  Apparently `Graph`-related functionality is implemented at a low level, and currently has several weird bugs (e.g. doesn't play well with packed arrays).  Looking forward to a 8.0.2 that'll fix these.

Comment: I am glad I am using version 7!

Comment: This has been incredibly useful for working around several (but not all!) obscure Graph-related kernel crash bugs as well.  I'm using Leonid's solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are not going to perform some string manipulations on the resulting string, you may consider `Compress` and `Uncompress` as an alternative to `ToString`. While I don't know about cases where `ToString[expr,InputForm]` - `ToExpression` cycles would break, I can easily imagine that they exist. The `Compress` solution seems more robust, as `Uncompress` invoked on `Compress`-ed string is guaranteed to reconstruct the original expression. An added advantage of `Compress` is that it is pretty memory-efficient - I used it a few times to save large amounts of numerical data in the notebook, without saving them to disk.

Comment: Do you know what compression method it uses, and its performance? (Same as gzip? Which is very fast.)  It's interesting to note that `Uncompress@Compress[...]` will also preserve the "packedness" of arrays.  I assume that the `Compress` output is portable between architectures, despite this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the details on internal implementation of `Compress` - perhaps more knowledgeable people here could comment on that. For my purposes, this was pretty fast, even for large amounts of data/large expressions. Regarding portability, you may very well be right (this would be nice), but again, I don't know.

Comment: I implemented most of the Compress function in Mathematica.  It uses "deflate" compression, the same as gzip.  It is portable across all the architectures on which Mathematica is available.  It maintains packed arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Should `Compress` exhibit round-tripping problems, `ExportString` and `ImportString` might present a useful alternative -- particularly, if they are used in conjunction with the Mathematica-native `MX` format:

```
string = ExportString[originalExpr, "MX"]
recoveredExpr = ImportString[string, "MX"]
```

Note that the `MX` format is not generally transferable between Mathematica instances, but that might not matter for the described in-memory application.

`ExpressionML` is another Mathematica-related export format, but it is distinctly *not* a compact format.

Comment: I was worried this would preserve the broken representation that made `IsomorphicGraphQ` fails, but in fact it doesn't.  @WReach, generally, is it safe to use strings for binary data?

Comment: @Szabolcs Empirically, I would say yes.  I have used a similar strategy with encoded image files successfully in the past.  The strings seem to act like an array of 16-bit words and I have observed no ill effects.  I cannot give a stronger assurance, however.

Comment: Albert Retey has [pointed out](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/e7c4be8aeb5c7b9e) recently the existence of the Wolfram Data Exchange ("WDX") format which is another alternative to the "MX" format.